# Deadlock in parallel quicksort in Go

Tags: parallel-processing, go, deadlock, quicksort

As an exercise I'm trying to implement a parallel version of quicksort in Go. This is what I have so far:

```
func quicksort(nums []int, ch chan int, level int, threads int)  {
  level *= 2;
  if len(nums) == 1 {  ch<- nums[0]; close(ch); return }

  less := make([]int, 0)
  greater := make([]int,0)
  pivot := nums[0]
  nums = nums[1:]

  for _,i := range nums{
    switch{
    case i <= pivot:
      less = append(less,i)
    case i > pivot:
      greater = append(greater,i)
    }
  }

  ch1 := make(chan int, len(less))
  ch2 := make(chan int, len(greater))
  if(level <= threads){
    go quicksort(less, ch1, level, threads)
    go quicksort(greater,ch2, level, threads)
  }else{
    quicksort(less,ch1, level, threads)
    quicksort(greater,ch2, level, threads)
  }

  for i := range ch1{
    ch<-i;
  }
  ch<-pivot
  for i := range ch2{
    ch<-i;
  }
  close(ch)
  return
}
```

However, when I run it, I get an error claiming the program has deadlocked! I'm pretty stumped to what is causing this...

Thanks in advance,

Linus

Comment: Is that you, Linus??? ;-)

Comment: Well, yes :). Not sure if I'm the Linus you're looking for.

Comment: If you provide a full program and the panic, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Can you put your program on http://play.golang.org? This way, it will be much easier to spot the error.

Comment: I put this on play.golang.org at http://play.golang.org/p/Ozcb5Axbzj -- not sure if I'm calling it right, but I don't get a deadlock, I get "panic: runtime error: index out of range". I also notice that the pivot gets sent on the channel twice. It's in `less` (because it's less than or equal to itself) so the recursive call will pass it through ch1, then ch, but then it's also sent explicitly (`ch <- pivot`). Am I misreading the code?

Comment: I'm wrong, you do a `[:1]` to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has one problem, and at least one potential buggy usage case:

1. It is missing a base case.  Consider what happens if `quicksort` is asked to sort the empty slice.
2. When calling `quicksort` for the first time, say in a `main()`, if you don't spawn the sorter in a separate goroutine, the main thread, running the toplevel sort, can block trying to write back to the channel (depending if the toplevel channel itself is buffered).

For example:

```
func main() {
    x := []int{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6}
    ch := make(chan int)
    quicksort(x, ch, 0, 0)    // buggy!
    for v := range(ch) {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

This is buggy because this asks the main thread to do the sort, but it will inevitably block at this part of `quicksort`: it can't communicate with itself!

```
for i := range ch1{
    ch<-i;
}
```

and it's at the write to the toplevel channel here that the main thread will deadlock.

Contrast this with what happens if we do create a goroutine at toplevel:

```
func main() {
    x := []int{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6}
    ch := make(chan int)
    go quicksort(x, ch, 0, 0)
    for v := range(ch) {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

and now we avoid that particular deadlock problem.

Comment: Thanks! Launching the sort as a go routine did the trick :). I do have a new question though, because somehow (even after setting GOMAXPROCS to my number of cores) my parallel version takes about 150% more time than my sequential version... It seems to me this is a fairly well parallelizable problem, and go routines should be pretty light... Even with N=100000, parallel is much slower...

Comment: @Linus Goroutines are cheap *relative* to OS threads. Go's concurrency primitives are more suited toward coarsely grained parallelism. The design you've chosen in your solution looks like finely grained parallelism to me. I suggest you ask a new question regarding the performance of your quicksort. Please include benchmarks!